# Slurm: can i create e sub-queue using a subset of resources in a single node?

Tags: linux, slurm

I have a use case with slurm and I wonder if there is a way to handle it.

**Constraints**:

1. I would like to run several jobs (say 60 jobs).
2. Each one takes a few hours, e.g. 3h/job.
3. In the cluster managed by slurm, I use a queue with 2 nodes with 4 gpus each (so I can restrict my batch script to one node).
4. Each job takes 1 gpu.

**Problem**: if I put everything in the queue, I will block 4 gpus even if I specify only 1 node.

**Desired solution**: avoid blocking a whole machine by taking, say, 2 gpus only.

How can I put them in the queue without them taking all 4 gpus?

Could I create a kind of sub-file that would be limited to a subset of resources of a node for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Slurm consumable trackable resources plug-in (`cons_tres` enabled in your `slurm.conf` file- more info here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/cons_res.html#using_cons_tres) to:

Specify the `--gpus-per-task=X`

-or-

Bind a specific number of gpus to the task with `--gpus=X`

-or-

Bind the task to a specific gpu by its ID with `--gpu-bind=GPUID`